# Angular multiple moduels routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I have to modules, where the secound module is lazy loaded during routing through `auth`. The main module `app` module with routing looks as following:

```ts
const app_routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, outlet: 'app', pathMatch: 'full', 
  canActivate: [OauthGuard]},
  { path: 'auth', loadChildren: 'app/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, outlet: 'app' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(app_routes)],
  providers: [OauthGuard],
 bootstrap: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here navigationg to `auth` loads the `AuthenticationModule`.

```ts
const auth_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    outlet: 'app',
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        outlet: 'auth'
      }
    ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(auth_routes),
    UtilsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AuthenticationComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ClientService,
    AuthenticationService
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [
    AuthenticationComponent
  ]
})

export class AuthenticationModule {
}
```

According to my logic `LoginComponent` should be loaded on the `auth` router-outlet when navigation to `auth/login`. But instead i get this error message:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/login'

As suggested i logged routes registered when `canActivate()`gets called on first route change getting this:

```ts
Routes:  [
  {
    "path": "",
    "outlet": "app",
    "pathMatch": "full",
    "canActivate": [
      null
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "auth",
    "loadChildren": "app/authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule"
  },
  {
    "path": "**",
    "outlet": "app"
  }
]
```

Routes registered are the same in the ran from the àuthentication.module` constructor.

I realy have no idea why i still get this error. Any tips?

Comment: I just checked with the Angular doc team and this syntax: `{ path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => AuthenticationModule}` does not do lazy loading. It  to builds up the route tree using modules without lazy loading.

Comment: You can inspect the total of your routes registered with [this small code block](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#inspect-config)

Comment: Also, you could consider adding route tracing so you can better see what your routes are trying to do: ` , { enableTracing: true }` added as the second parameter to the forRoot method after the array of routes.

Comment: Also, consider not using a named outlet. Remove the `outlet: 'app',` This interferes with the normal routing because a named (secondary) outlet is *not* the same as a child outlet.

Comment: Thanks @DeborahK used the module path and class name insted, also updated the question with a previous result of routes registered before `AuthenticationModule` gets loaded.

Comment: Trying again with `enbaleTracing` set. Could the `outlet` name be part of what is giving me the unmatched error?

Comment: Yes, I would think it could be the problem ...

Comment: It fixed the `**` redirect route, but not much more. Tracing was just what i was looking for earlier, unfortunately it did not help much in this case.

Comment: Still no success, i can reach the `/auth` path and load the module, but non of the routes added in the second module `forChild()`  is accessable.

Comment: Can you post your current code? Or better yet, work up a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help i resolved the issue, where the problem was the outlet names. I was unaware that it was possible to have multiple unnamed `router-outlets` as long as they belongs to different scopes. So what I did was simply to remove the outlet names. With my old code I would have to navigate to `/auth(auth:login)` where `(auth:login)` specifies the outlet name and child route to display. Without outlet names i can simply navigate to `auth/login` and i reach the desired page.

#### authentication.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthenticationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'register',
        component: RegisterComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]}
];
```